# Browser resize issue How to fix?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am having trouble when I resize the browser using to a smaller size.  The text and divs get distorted and shift or move instead of staying in place.  I do not know how to fix it.  Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

***HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"</div>
    <div id="logo"><h2>Logo</h2></div>
        <div id="navbar">
        <a href=""><h3 class="navlink">Home</h3></a>
        <a href=""><h3 class="navlink">About Me</h3></a>
        <a href=""><h3 class="navlink">Tips and Tricks</h3></a>
        <a href=""><h3 class="navlink">Contact Me</h3></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content"><h1>Content</h1><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit tenetur sint sapiente similique laborum eius nisi, repellat ratione deleniti, inventore accusantium ut corporis reiciendis eum enim. Expedita nostrum error. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit repellat dolore fugiat ab ut quisquam dicta atque aliquid sapiente, autem veniam placeat id quod tempore culpa! Velit sint, molestias nesciunt.</h2>


</div>
<div id="menu"><h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gaming</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Television</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Music</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="footer"><h2>Footer</h2></div>


</div>


</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***Stylesheet.css:***

```
#body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: 0ddfff;
}

#logo {
    width: 20%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#navbar {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.navlink {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 2%;
}

#content {
    width: 60%;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}

#menu {
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
    margin-left: 19.4%;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 60%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make it responsive ?

Comment: copy and past your css.

Comment: Yes I want it responsive.  I did paste my css.

Answer (score 0):

You have used percentage unit for width(Example: `#logo{width:20%;}`so while opening page in small screen it display percentage of current screen width. You have two option to fix this issue.

1) Use pixel unit instead of percentage.
2) Use [media-query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and write css for small resolution (Responsive Layout).

Comment: How do I use media-query for small resolution?  I just want it to be able to resize properly without issue.

Comment: Find the standard device resolution below and write css http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're using responsive styles (defining widths and positions in terms of %) when you seem to actually want specific widths on the elements.  It's not very clear what you want to happen when you resize the browser, but here's a quick overview:

- If you want your element to always be the same size, define its width and height in terms of pixels, like so (you will also probably want to define your margins the same way):  width: 400px; height: 20px;
- If you want your element to always be a quarter page width from the left, you can do something like: margin-left: 25%;
- If you want your element to resize up until a certain point, follow what's being done for the #container element css styles by specifying a min-width or max-width.

Some additional things I feel like I should mention:

- In your CSS, you refer to body as #body, however you do not have a div with an id of body, so this style is not referring to anything.  You may want to change that css style so that it says body instead since body is a tag.
- This is an issue:  < div id="header" < /div>, it's missing an ">" before the closing tag, however it's unclear whether or not you wanted the items below it to nest inside.  Things like this can prevent some of your styles from being taken the way you expect.

Comment: I fixed header.  Nothing happened.  I changed the body tag.  Nothing happened.  What can I do to fix it to be responsive?  I just want it to adjust according to the size or resize of the browser.

Comment: Your site is already responsive, that's what it means when you have widths in terms of % rather than px.  Change whatever you don't want to resize to be in px, otherwise it's in terms of the parent container's width.  Set a min-width on anything you don't want to become any smaller but still be responsive.

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed that issue.  Another question.  I wanted to know how do you set it to a fluid or elastic design layout?

Comment: It's technically already in a fluid/elastic design layout since it uses %, min-width and media queries to define the positions/widths, but you can use something like Twitter Bootstrap or something lighter weight like http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ to set up something more consistent.